# What is a single word for a person who wants badly to hold a place in history?

Tags: personality

He wants to be REMEMBERED forever by the people like Abraham Lincoln or Adolf Hitler

Comment: What has your research shown?  Please consult references and include them in your question as to what stumped you.

Comment: Legacy-obsessed. This is an swr without a proper tag or required sentence.

Answer (score 1):

David McClelland, the American psychologist, formulated his theory of motivation wherein he proposed the *need for achievement*. I think it is quite relevant to your question and you might want to read further about it ***[here](https://www.yourarticlelibrary.com/entrepreneurship/motivation-entrepreneurship/mcclellands-need-for-achievement-theory/40683)***.